# How can I approach writing a GUI framework for my game?

Tags: c#, architecture, gui, software-engineering, methodology

### The problem

I want to write a simple GUI framework designed for a game, in order to learn the inner workings and nitty-gritty of how GUI 'engines' such as Unity3D's GUI work. I can't find any resource to help me get started.

What I'm looking for exactly is the abstract methodology of GUI programming, so things like what are the components of a GUI framework, how often and in what ways should the interface be updated with data, what are the different ways to connect the visuals in the interface to the logic behind them, how should clicking events be handled, things like that.

### What I tried

I've been trying to research my options for months but to no avail. Looking up keywords like "GUI programming" or "GUI programming philosophies" leads nowhere and doesn't answer the questions I mentioned above.

There are plenty of resources and tutorials out there for things like OpenGL, how to write a game loop, how to write a physics engine, but nothing like that for writing GUI systems. The wikipedia pages for these topics are also usually a good starting point, but the GUI entries are too design-focused, failing to focus on programming-specific methodology/architecture.

I also tried starting from the web GUI frameworks I know such as React and Angular, and learned a few interesting things like the the view-model-viewmodel architecture and React's virtual DOM, but I still don't know how to apply them, how to generalize them into some framework/philosophy I can follow while coding, and whether there are any other possible options.

P.S. My environment is C# and OpenGL through [OpenTK](https://opentk.net/), but that hopefully won't matter in terms of respondents giving a broad overview.

Comment: As you suspected, this question is too broad to suit our Q&A format here. However, it looks like you've got enough reputation already to ask in a less-formally-structured context like [chat]. There you might be able to get some of your initial uncertainties sorted out, and you can come back here to refine your question to a more specific topic we can re-open.

Comment: @DMGregory sweet, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @DMGregory I can answer this question with reasonable accuracy. Can we bring it back to life, please? I've issued a re-open vote. I'd only suggest that the OP removes the "what are some resources" part as we don't accept list-type questions.

Comment: @Engineer I can edit it- could you suggest an alternative format for the question?

Comment: @Engineer please feel free to make the edits you consider appropriate — it's easy to roll them back if OP disagrees. The question is now in the reopen queue, so if other users agree that your edits narrow it to an answerable scope, they can vote to re-open it, so the process isn't bottlenecked on convincing any one moderator.

Comment: @H. Saleh I've now edited your question a little. It is otherwise well-written. Let's hope it gets re-opened shortly.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks; feel free to contribute on that queue if it looks acceptable to you. In future, let's maybe not rush to place on hold / close so quickly.

Comment: I still feel like this question is way too broad for this site. And questions that are in a too broad state need to be put on hold, that's how the site works.